# How to optimize a simple LINQ query with two related tables?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two related tables with the following structure:

'patients' :

```
{ Id = 1, Surname = Smith998 }
...
{ Id = 1000, Surname = Smith1000 }
```

and the second is 'receptions' :

```
{ PatientId = 1, ReceptionStart = 3/3/2017 1:14:00 AM }
{ PatientId = 1, ReceptionStart = 1/7/2016 1:14:00 AM }
...
{ PatientId = 1000, ReceptionStart = 1/23/2017 1:14:00 AM }
```

the tables are not from a database, but they are generated with the following sample code:

```
        var rand = new Random();
        var receptions = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).SelectMany(pid => Enumerable.Range(1, rand.Next(0, 10)).Select(rid => new { PatientId = pid, ReceptionStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-rand.Next(1, 500)) })).ToList();
        var patients = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).Select(pid => new { Id = pid, Surname = string.Format("Smith{0}", pid) }).ToList();
```

The question is what is the optimal way to select the patients that have receptions before 1/1/2017?

Of cause I can write something like this:

```
        var cured_receptions = (from r in receptions where r.ReceptionStart < new DateTime(2017, 7, 1) select r.PatientId).Distinct();
        var cured_patients = from p in patients where cured_receptions.Contains(p.Id) select p;
```

but it is not clear for me what 'cured_receptions.Contains(p.Id)' code actually does? Does it simply iterate over all the patients searching the Id or it use something like indices in a database? Can cured_receptions.ToDictionary() or something like this help here somehow?

Comment: You can put a join between two queries and do it in a single step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting over assuming everything in memory only...

1. Your `cured_receptions` isn't evaluated until called by the `Contains` so it would be much more efficient use put `.ToList()` on the end of that variable definition (about 100X faster).
2. LINQ doesn't "search" - `Contains` is doing the searching. If you want to use something like a binary search or better still, a hash table, you must create it. If you do use a `HashSet<int>` then you will gain another 47X speedup. Taking the `Distinct` off (since the `HashSet` will handle that) saves another 15%.
3. Remembering your constants in variables instead of creating them as you go (`new DateTime`...) may save a little more. Even greatly increasing your random data doesn't take up enough time to tell with the `HashSet`.
4. Using a `join` is faster than your initial query, but your query combined with a `HashSet` is fastest.

So the fastest code is:

```
var cured_receptions = new HashSet<int>((from r in receptions where r.ReceptionStart < endDateTime select r.PatientId));
var cured_patients = from p in patients where cured_receptions.Contains(p.Id) select p;
```

Note: I used LINQPad to generate timings and sample data. I changed your date parameters because your values made the majority of receptions match.

Here is the code from my LINQPad:

```
var rand = new Random();
var begin = DateTime.Now;
var receptions = Enumerable.Range(1, 100000).SelectMany(pid => Enumerable.Range(1, rand.Next(0, 100)).Select(rid => new { PatientId = pid, ReceptionStart = begin.AddDays(-rand.Next(1, 180)) })).ToList();
var patients = Enumerable.Range(1, 100000).Select(pid => new { Id = pid, Surname = string.Format("Smith{0}", pid) }).ToList();

var startTime = Util.ElapsedTime;
var endDateTime = new DateTime(2017, 5, 1);
//var cured_receptions = (from r in receptions where r.ReceptionStart < new DateTime(2017, 5, 1) select r.PatientId).Distinct().ToList();
//var cured_receptions = (from r in receptions where r.ReceptionStart < new DateTime(2017, 5, 1) select r.PatientId).Distinct();
//var cured_receptions = new HashSet<int>((from r in receptions where r.ReceptionStart < new DateTime(2017, 5, 1) select r.PatientId).Distinct());
//var cured_receptions = new HashSet<int>((from r in receptions where r.ReceptionStart < endDateTime select r.PatientId).Distinct());
//var cured_receptions = new HashSet<int>((from r in receptions where r.ReceptionStart < new DateTime(2017, 5, 1) select r.PatientId));
var cured_receptions = new HashSet<int>((from r in receptions where r.ReceptionStart < endDateTime select r.PatientId));
var cured_patients = from p in patients where cured_receptions.Contains(p.Id) select p;

//  var cured_patients = (from r in receptions
//                       where r.ReceptionStart < endDateTime
//                       join p in patients on r.PatientId equals p.Id
//                       select p).Distinct();

//  var cured_patients = from p in patients
//                       join r in receptions on p.Id equals r.PatientId into rj
//                       where rj.Any(r => r.ReceptionStart < endDateTime)
//                       select p;

cured_patients.Count().Dump();
var endTime = Util.ElapsedTime;

(endTime - startTime).Dump("Elapsed");
```

Comment: My items are in memory, but not in a database.

Comment: Didn't catch that in your comment. Changed to explain in memory.

Comment: Very good idea about HashSet! But I cannot figure out about #1 - what is the difference between .ToList() and original cured_receptions? From my point of view they both are some kind of containers with O(N) search, aren't they?

Comment: No - without the `.ToList()`, `cured_receptions` is an `IEnumerable` that is computed on the fly per reception returned, and recomputing from the start per patient. OTOH, with the `ToList`, the computation is done once to extract all the answers and put in a list. So both are O(N) search, but one of them is also scanning for matching `ReceptionStart` and putting the `PatientId`s in a `HashSet` or equivalent to process the `Distinct`, per patient.

Answer (score 0):

> but it is not clear for me what 'cured_receptions.Contains(p.Id)' code actually does? Does it simply iterate over all the patients searching the Id or it use something like indices in a database?

**Case 1: Interacting with Database**

If you were interacting with the database then no query will be sent to the database until you execute the 2nd query by calling `ToList()` on it or by iterating the items in `cured_patients`. The query sent to the database will be something along the lines:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Surname] AS [Surname]
FROM [dbo].[Patients] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Receptions] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE ([Extent2].[ReceptionStart] < 
    convert(datetime2, '2017-07-01 00:00:00.0000000', 121)) 
    AND ([Extent2].[PatientId] = [Extent1].[Id])
)
```

> Will it use any indices?

Yes if `PatientId`, `Id` and `ReceptionStart` are indexed, then the database server will use them.

**Case 2: Interacting with items in memory**

For the first query it will iterate all `receptions`, find the ones whose `ReceptionStart` is before the given date, select the `PatientId` and then remove any duplicate `PatientId`(s).

Then the 2nd query which is below:

```
var cured_patients = 
   from p in patients 
   where cured_receptions.Contains(p.Id) 
   select p;
```

Will iterate each item in `patients` and see if the `Id` of that item is found in `cured_receptions`. For all the items whose `Id` is found in the `cured_receptions`, it will select those items. `Contains` simply returns a `true` or `false`.

Comment: Is it possible to optimize the query somehow when my items are in memory, but not in the database? Does LINQ operate on maps or hash tables? Why LINQ cannot do a binary search in an ordered set?

Comment: @user2394762 Why do you want to optimize it? Is it slow and is this piece of code the bottleneck? .NET has [BinarySearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f90y839(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Note that since `cured_receptions` is an `IEnumerable<>` - the variable definition doesn't iterate anything, just creates the stacked LINQ `IEnumerable` functions. The `Contains` will execute the `cured_receptions` for each `p`, re-computing the elements every time up until it finds a match for `p.Id`.

Comment: That is not a part of a real project, but it is some testing task assuming an optimization, so I am asking about it.

Comment: So cured_receptions will be recomputed 1000 times? Or I misunderstood something in your comments?